# $watch en variable intanciada con controllerAs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Como hacer un $watch a una variable creada a partir de una instancia de mi controller usando la notación controllerAs por ejemplo

```
var vm = this;

vm.myVariable = [];

$scope.$watch('vm.myVariable',function(newValue){
  console.log(newValue);
});
```

lo tengo de esta manera pero no obtengo el resultado deseado, ¿Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Hola, como estas declarando tu controllerAs?? que error tienes en la consola???  ya que si miras este ejemplo que hice esta [igual](https://plnkr.co/edit/yZmqgeTz3AZqvK72AQPe?p=preview)

Comment: ¿estas inyectando el $scope a tu controller?

Comment: Asegurate que en la parte donde declaras controllerAs="ct" también uses `$scope.$watch('ct.propiedad')` ya que si tienes varios controllers anidados puede ser que escogieras otro valor en lugar de `vm`

Comment: @WilfredoP Mi respuesta erronea se originó por este [bug](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/issues/449) y este [bug](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/issues/428) de la guía de John Papa. Al parecer se actualizó esa sección. También por este [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078535/angularjs-controller-as-syntax-and-watch) pero tienes razón, usualmente este bug se debe a la propiedad mal referenciada ;P

Comment: @devconcept Si por lo general es eso. Me pareció rara tu respuesta.

Comment: Hola, ¿te sirvió la respuesta? si es así te agradecería que la aceptaras para que pueda ayudar a otros usuarios y para que no aparezca periódicamente como "sin responder". Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Cuando se usa la estructura "controllerAs", el controlador de añega al scope con el nombre se ha establecido aquí.

Lo mas probable es que te esté ocurriendo lo que dice [devconcept](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2224/devconcept) en uno de los comentarios, es decir, que a la hora de declarar el nombre del controlador le estés asignando un nombre distinto a `vm`.

Por ejemplo:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl as viewModel">
  Hello, {{viewModel.name}}!
</div> 

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.name = 'Superhero';
  ...
}
```

Cuando se usa la estructura "controllerAs" hay que evitar hacer los `$scope.$watch` usando una expresión para así no depender del nombre que se asigna al controlador desde la vista.

La forma de hacerlo sería esta:

```
$scope.$watch(function(scope){
    return vm.name;
}, function(newValue, oldValue){
    console.log('New name: ' + newValue);
});
```

Puedes ver el ejemplo completo en [este JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/2164/) y en [este artículo en inglés](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2852-understanding-how-to-use-scope-watch-with-controller-as-in-angularjs.htm) está explicado con más detalle.